# How do I show that this function is a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Assume $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$. Let $f:R^N \to R^N$ with $$f_i(x) \equiv \frac{x_i^\alpha}{\sum x_j^\alpha}$$

How do I show that this function is a contraction?

Comment: How do we define $f(x)$ when one of the coordinates of $x$ is negative?

Comment: You don't need $f_i(x)$ to be positive.

Comment: I should have to specified that $x_i \ge \epsilon \gt 0$ for all $i$

Comment: @Igor: but how are we defining $x^\alpha$ when $x\lt0$?

Comment: @Andres: thanks.

Comment: @robjohn: thanks, I didn't think about those values of $\alpha$! Also, we can't divide by zero...

Answer (score 0):

By [definition of the contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping), you need to show that there exists such $0\leq k < 1$ that $$d(f(x), f(y))\leq k d(x, y)$$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^N$

Now, here the distance $d$ is a normal euclidian distance on $\mathbb{R}^N$, so this boils down to proving that 
$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (f_i(x) - f_i(y))^2}\leq k\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2}.$$

Try substituting the expressions for $f_i(x)$ and $f_i(y)$ into this inequality and see what you get!

Comment: I get that I would need to find $0<k<1$ such that for all $y$ and $x$ with $y_i,x_i\ge \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \gt 0$  $$\sum_j \left(\frac{y_j^\alpha}{\sum y_k^\alpha} - \frac{x_j^\alpha}{\sum x_k^\alpha} \right)^2 \le k \sum_j (y_j-x_j)^2$$ Any hints on how to work this out?

Comment: I think I found a counterexample. Take N = 2 and $\alpha$ =1/2. Consider the vectors y = (0.9,0.1) and x = (0.95, 0.05). I get f(y) = (0.81,0.17) and f(x) = (0.75, 0.25). The Euclidian distance between y and x is 0.07 while that between f(x) and f(y) is 0.89. (All approx. numbers.) This is very surprising -- I was pretty sure that the function with $\alpha \le 1/2$ was a contraction mapping.

Comment: Check your distance between f(x) and f(y), I get 0.089. So, I don't think that it is a counterexample, since it works with $k = 0.5$ (or $k = 0.05$, for your values).

Comment: Thanks. You are right, distance is 0.089. But that is still higher than 0.07. It's supposed to be lower for a contraction.

Comment: You keep forgetting about your $k$ constant. One case can't prove anything, because you can always find such $k$ that the equation holds (in your case, it would be 0.5... or take 0.01 to be sure). I still haven't figured out how to prove that such $k$ exists that fits all $x$ and $y$... Those fractions are killing me :(

Comment: But if $k = 0.5$ then $d(f(x),f(y))=0.089 \gt kd(x,y)=0.5*0.07=0.035$

Comment: Oh, you're right! I was thinking the wrong direction!